# bootstrap datepicker won't load from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

When I load the datepicker through the  `data-provide="datepicker"`, it will show up but not in safari.  I also need to block out dates, such as the weekend.   I was thinking both problems could be solved loading it through javascript and throwing in some config variables but I'm getting an error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I'm thinking it's because maybe the jquery is being loaded in the wrong order, but other functionality is working.

Test site is here: http://vtcol2015.com.php53-25.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/schedule-tour

Field for datepicker is under `Select your prefered day & time`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include the Jquery library before that Jquery code.

Add this in your html before that code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Your JS should look like this after adding:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#formfield_date-select').datepicker();
        console.log( "ready!" );
    });
</script>
```

**Update**

I noticed your Jquery library is at the bottom of the page. Move that above where the error occurs or much better inside the `<head></head>` section since Jquery will be used on most of your pages.

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap usually has a dependency on the jQuery library. If any other jQuery code is being executed, then you have a conflict for the `$` symbol reference in the bootstrap library.

The jQuery [page](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) on `jQuery.noCoflict()` is quite helpful.

One simple solution is to create another jQuery variable reference.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Do something with jQuery
j( "div p" ).hide();

// Do something with another library's $() - bootstrap in your case
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```